# Why does the variable I attach `this` to in the constructor lose its binding?

Tags: javascript

I'm really beating my head against this one. I cannot figure out how javascript's binding works. In the constructor of my class, I set `var self = this;`, which I thought would forever give me an absolute reference to my instance. However, that doesn't seem to be the case at all.

Below is the primary structure of my class.

```
var MyClass = (function() {
    function MyClass(data) {
        var self = this; 
        this._element = $('.someSelector');   
    }

    MyClass.prototype.styleIt = function() {
        self._element.css('display', 'block'); 
    }
    return MyClass;

})();
```

In another class, which holds instances of `MyClass`, I call the `styleIt` function as follows:

```
Class2:
...
    $('#id').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < self._objects.length; i++) {
            [i].styleIt(); 
        }
    }
```

However, confusingly (to me) the `self` inside of `styleIt` is bound to `window`! What is happening here?

Comment: Your `self` is inside the function `MyClass`. The function you are adding to the `prototype` isn't enclosed by that function so it doesn't have access to `self`. Instead you are creating a global (attached to `window`) called `self`

Comment: Also `MyClass` as a variable as well as a function name is just confusing and probably asking for trouble.

Comment: And another reason why [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.self) is a bad variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is defined inside of the inner `MyClass` function and thus is only visible within that scope.   Your styleIt method is not defined within that scope and thus cannot see the `self` variable.

If you want your methods to be self-referential (e.g. not rely on `this`), then you have to define the methods within the constructor (not on the prototype) so they can see the `self` variable.

Here's one way to do that:

```
var MyClass = (function() {
    function MyClass(data) {
        var self = this; 
        this._element = $('.someSelector');   

        this.styleIt = function() {
            self._element.css('display', 'block'); 
            return self;
        }
    }

})();
```

---

In your code that calls `styleIt()` like this:

```
$('#id').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < self._objects.length; i++) {
        [i].styleIt(); 
    }
}
```

this code is simply not correct (two coding errors) and should not need the self referential feature above.  This code can be done like this:

```
$('#id').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < self._objects.length; i++) {
        self._objects[i].styleIt(); 
    }
}
```

When calling a method using `obj.method()` `this` will be set to `obj` inside of the method so you wouldn't need the `self` feature in the `styleIt()` method.  You could just rely on the value of `this`.